# mysql Rollup sums to 0 on some columns

Tags: mysql, rollup

I have a Rollup query in mysql to create the weekly report and i want to sum up the numbers in the last row:

```
SELECT case when ISNULL(Datum) then 'Summe' ELSE Datum end AS Datum,
            `Anzahl angenommen`,
            `unvollständig`,
            KDA,
            Freigabe
    FROM(
    SELECT F.eindat AS Datum,
            COUNT(F.eindat) AS 'Anzahl angenommen',
            COUNT(T.blocker)  AS 'unvollständig',
            case when B.KDA IS NULL then 0 ELSE B.KDA END AS KDA,
            case when P.Freigabe IS NULL then 0 ELSE P.Freigabe END AS Freigabe
    FROM mukl.fall F
    left JOIN mukl.ticket T ON T.fall = F.ID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT F.beadat AS Datum, COUNT(F.beadat) AS KDA
                    FROM mukl.fall F
                    WHERE F.eindat >= '2021-08-07'
                    GROUP BY F.beadat) B ON B.Datum = F.eindat
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT F.prudat AS Datum, COUNT(F.prudat) AS Freigabe
                    FROM mukl.fall F
                    WHERE F.eindat >= '2021-08-07'
                    GROUP BY F.prudat) P ON P.Datum = F.eindat
    WHERE F.eindat >= '2021-08-07'
    GROUP BY F.eindat WITH rollup
    ) AS DT
```

Sadly the output is only partly what i want:

[image]

The first two columns are summed up correctly, the last two just display as 0, although the sum is not 0. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

please try with this pseudocode

```
-- MySQL (v5.8)
SELECT CASE WHEN datum IS NULL THEN 'sum' ELSE datum END dat
     , SUM(a) a, SUM(b) b
     , SUM(c) c, SUM(d) d
FROM test
GROUP BY datum WITH ROLLUP;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=19fdd64ce99647ce751004b1580766d1

In your query use aggregate function of all columns except GROUP BY columns

```
   SELECT F.eindat AS Datum,
            COUNT(F.eindat) AS 'Anzahl angenommen',
            COUNT(T.blocker)  AS 'unvollständig',
            SUM(case when B.KDA IS NULL then 0 ELSE B.KDA END) AS KDA,
            SUM(case when P.Freigabe IS NULL then 0 ELSE P.Freigabe END) AS Freigabe
```

Comment: hi @momo please check my query and let me know if you've any question regard this.

Comment: So this works as it displays a sum in the last row, but it completely changes what is summed up, so i cannot use it sadly...
Maybe my statement itself is wrong

Comment: ok @momo thanks your reply. As per your requirement you can use any aggregate function like MIN, MAX etc. And also check your data at non aggregate column.